# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props' due to one line in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-props, react-functional-component

In my react app, there is a useEffect. This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const trimmedArray = trimArray(props.firstInputValue);
        props.setFirstFinalSetArray(trimmedArray);
        setFirstPrintArray(`{${trimmedArray.join(', ')}}`);
    }, [props.firstInputValue]);
```

1. This useeffect is used in a functional component.
2. `trimArray` is a function
3. `setFirstFinalSetArray` is a useState set function.
4. `setFirstPrintArray` is state in current component.
5. `firstInputValue` is state in parent component.

And I found due to this line : props.setFirstFinalSetArray(trimmedArray);
I am getting this error: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: Did you read the warning? Did you consider making the changes suggested?

Comment: I read the warning. I just dont understand what this warning is suggesting. I am not sure what to do after removing that prop. I need use that prop inside useeffect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure your props like:

```
const MyComponent = ({firstInputValue, setFirstFinalSetArray}) => {
  const [firstPrintArray, setFirstPrintArray] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    const trimmedArray = trimArray(firstInputValue);
    setFirstFinalSetArray(trimmedArray);
    setFirstPrintArray(`{${trimmedArray.join(', ')}}`);
  }, [firstInputValue, setFirstFinalSetArray]);

  // rest of your code
}
```

When I was learning React I was hesitant to do this for whatever reason (I liked having `props` I guess), but it really does make for clean code.